# how to create two branches for a observable pipe. I am not talking about iif

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let me explain. I have a subscription that returns an object with properties. The history property usually fetches a string, but it can also be null. How could I deal to separate 2 branches. I mean, if the value of the history property is a string, return it, if it is null display 'No history'. I am aware of operator iif, but in this case the doubt is not about a conditional which retrieve one or another observable, I mean inside the same observable flow.

```
this.historyResult$ = this.historyObject$.pipe(
                            pluck('history')
                            );
```

To sum up: My question is, could I set something like a conditional to say: if the value of history is null then for example user the operator mapTo ('No history') in order to retrieve 'No history' string???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply use a `map` operator. If `x.history` is `undefined` then the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??` returns the string `"No history"` by the anonymous function inside of `map`. So that either the `history` property or the string is emitted:

```
this.historyResult$ = this.historyObject$.pipe(
  map((x) =>
    x.history ?? "No history"
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `filter`-operator (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter)

Using this operator you'd be able to filter by an absent value by:

```js
this.historyResult$ = this.historyObject$.pipe(
    pluck('history'),
    filter((history) => !!history)
);
```

That way your observable will never produce a `null` or `undefined` value.

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to display a result in case of property value is equal to null. In this case that result would be obviated

Comment: Ahhh, I misread your question... I see that @kruschid answered your question